# SQL display database on age range

Tags: sql, range

I'm using an Oracle database.

What do I have to do to print all data within the age range of 21 to 40?

```
CREATE TABLE    EMPLOYEE(
  ENum      varchar2(10)    not null,
  EName     varchar2(70),
  EDOB      date,
  ECity     varchar2(70),
  EStreet       varchar2(70),
  EHouse#            varchar2(10),

  constraint employee_pkey primary key (ENum)
);
```

I have a rough idea which look like this, but I know it's wrong because AGE is not a valid identifier. So should I use Select Case instead?

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE Age = ((sysdate - EDOB)/365.25)
AND EDOB BETWEEN 21 and 40;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

where ((sysdate - edob)/365.25) between 21 and 40

Comment: sorry but why is this able to work? don't we have include "something = //....." after the WHERE?

Comment: because if you put "something =" this somthing should be a column in the table or it can be expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE extract(year from sysdate) - extract(year from EDOB) 
BETWEEN 21 and 40;
```